# Max height attribute for jQuery select does not work in IE

Tags: jquery, css

I am using jquery select dropdown in my app. It seems to work fine with setting up other properties. But somehow max height is not getting updated. Here is the code that I used:

```
<script>
  $(function () {
      $("#ddlMonth").selectmenu();
  });
</script>
<style>
  select {
    max-height:100px;  //other properties work here
}
</style>
```

And the actual dropdown is created like this:

```
<select id="ddlMonth" onchange="fnSetMonth(this)"> ....  </select>
```

There are 12 items in the dropdown, but I want to show max 10 at once. Somehow in IE, it doesn't seem to work. My dropdown shows without any scrollbar with all 12 items.

What am I missing here??

Edit:
The application doesn't work in any other browser (forced compatibility), so can't test on other browsers. I am using IE10 in compatibility mode. Below is the reference to jQuery (found from the tutorial on select)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
```

Comment: Works in other browsers??

Comment: your missing the version of IE and the compatibility of the pulgin+jquery to that version

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use `_resizeMenu()` method:

> ### From the docs:
>
> #### *menuWidget()*
>
> ***Returns a jQuery object containing the menu element.***.
>
> This method does not accept any arguments.

There is no method available in the selectmenu api but on the sample page you can do this:

```js
$("#ddlMonth").selectmenu()
  .selectmenu("menuWidget")
  .addClass("overflow");
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 11px;
}
label {
  display: block;
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
}
select {
  width: 200px;
}
.overflow {
  max-height: 210px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<select name="ddlMonth" id="ddlMonth">
  <option>1</option>
  <option selected="selected">2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
  <option>8</option>
  <option>9</option>
  <option>10</option>
  <option>11</option>
  <option>12</option>
  <option>13</option>
  <option>14</option>
  <option>15</option>
  <option>16</option>
  <option>17</option>
  <option>18</option>
  <option>19</option>
</select>
```

Comment: That is the exact tutorial I am following. It works on chrome, but not in IE.

Comment: this tutorial uses height: 210px; and not max-height

Comment: check if **document mode** is also  at IE10 standards even if you are in compatibility mode.

Comment: and yes you can use `max-height`.

Comment: Browser mode is set to "IE 10", while document mode is set to IE5 Quirks. If I change that, it throws multiple errors in javascript (wherever `functionname(this)` is used as a function call.

Comment: boss then you have to rethink about it. IE10 is good one compare to other legacy versions.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about IE 10, but i know old IEs don't understand max-height.

Size attribute would be best.

```
<select id="ddlMonth" onchange="fnSetMonth(this)" size="10" > ....  </select>
```

I know people aren't going to like w3schools link below here. But is the quickest one i could find.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_size

Comment: jquery select does not have size property in css?

Comment: it is there in the question. :/ and i already tried size property on both normal and jquery select. that doesn't work on dropdown. it converts dropdowns to list.

Comment: Then what do you mean by show maximum 10 in a dropdown? .selectmenu(); what does that do?

Comment: Sorry just found out that jquery ui has selectmenu function. Lol. Haven;t used that before. what do you mean by show maximum 10 in a dropdown?

Comment: By default, select dropdown shows all the items (max 30 in IE, max 16 in Chrome..) it possibly can. So, if I have 20 items, IE will show all of them in one go, but chrome will show 16 and a scrollbar. I want to change that to always be at 10, no matter the browser. Both chrome and firefox support height for html select. According to google, IE supports height for jquery select. I can't figure out how to get it to work though.

Comment: Yes, all three options. Max, min and height set to 100px. Same issue.